# Silverlight deep zoom composing issue

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2008, deepzoom

Deep zoom composer itself is very nice tool. I am wondering if there are any automatic ways to compose? For example, I have 100 images, and I want to compose automatically as 10 * 10 deep zoom effect. I am implementing a background workflow and automatically composing deep zoom and publish. The Output Type I prefer is "Images" and "Export as a collection (multiple images)".

Any reference samples or documents? I am using VSTS2008 + C# + .Net 3.5.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22309050/23118).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/expression/archive/2008/11/26/hello-deepzoomtools-dll-deep-zoom-image-tile-generation-made-easy.aspx) about DeepZoomTools.dll included in the app.

Comment: Thanks link is very informative about object model, but as a beginner are there any runnable samples?

Answer (score 2):

There's a great sample project [here](http://blogs.sqlxml.org/bryantlikes/archive/2008/11/27/deep-zoom-image-generation-with-deepzoomtools-dll.aspx) and if you really want to go crazy and generate images/tiles programatically, you can try the sort of thing referenced in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943052.aspx).

I haven't found a lot of real documentation regarding DeepZoomTools.dll myself, but I created a small test webservice to turn a single uploaded image into a Deep Zoom source.  The relevant code is:

```
public string CreateDeepZoomImage(byte[] abyte, string fileName)
        {
            ImageCreator ic = new ImageCreator();
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(_uploadPath, fileName);
            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(abyte, 0, abyte.Length);
            fs.Close();
            FileInfo imageFileInfo = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            string destination = imageFileInfo.DirectoryName + "\\" + imageFileInfo.Name.TrimEnd(imageFileInfo.Extension.ToCharArray()) + "\\output.xml";
            ic.Create(FilePath, destination);
            string returnpath = "/Uploads/" + imageFileInfo.Name.TrimEnd(imageFileInfo.Extension.ToCharArray()) + "/output.xml";
            return returnpath;
        }
```

Where the return path is used like so:

```
ZoomImage.Source = new DeepZoomImageTileSource(new Uri(e.Result, UriKind.Relative));
```

(Forgive the sloppy code.  It does work though.)