# Deep Zoom Image - Command Line Tool? Or For Bulk Conversion

Tags: zooming, deepzoom, seadragon

I am looking for some kind of command line tool , using which I can create an application to convert input images into Deep Zoom Image.

I have around 500 images. I have used the Deep Zoom Composer to generate Deep Zoom Image[DZI] content one at a time. Was looking for a better way to process multiple images.

It looks like there was a tool SparseImageTool.exe in the Deep Zoom Installed Folder which is no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of tools for creating DZI and similar images:

http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/

Answer (score 3):

Found a command line tool which generates files for Deep Zoom.

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html

Example:

```
vips dzsave some-huge-file.tif my-dzi-name
```

Will write `my-dzi-name.dzi` and a directory called `my-dzi-name_files/` containing all the image tiles.